# autonumber field is not displaying on page layout for me

Tags: deployment

I have a custom object with many fields that I have added. They all work fine etc.  but I have created an AutoNumber field which does not appear once I create a new record. 
It appears in the Pagelayout preview screen all attribute has it as visible for all Profiles, but does not appear as said when I create the record. 
I have deleted and created new fields to try, if it change the field type from Auto Number to text, it will then appear.

Anyone have ideas? 
Thanks

Comment: There are 2 things Field level security where you set the fields visibility and there is a fields accessibility. Click on the accessibility and see if the field is hidden for all the profiles

Comment: Are you talking about the new/edit screen or the view page (shown when you've successfully saved)? Autonumbers don't show initially on "new" page, the value is unknown until the request hits the database.

Comment: @rao - You could move that to an answer...I'd upvote it! :)

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 things 
1) Set Field level security where you set the fields visibility and 
2) View field accessibility.

Click on the view field accessibility and see if the field is hidden for all the profiles

[image]